# Accessing adapter in android studios from another method

Tags: android, listview

I am implementing an android shopplinglist app and created a second button to remove all the items in ListView that gets the items from user input. As you can see, I implemented an adapter to add the items to the ListView. And as far as I know I need to access my adapter again, to delete the items. I am in the second onClick method and can't access my adapter that was created in the first onClick method. My code looks as follow:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
EditText txt;
ListView lst;
Button btn_delete;
ArrayList<String> arrylist = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    btn_delete =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getInput = txt.getText().toString();
            if (arrylist.contains(getInput)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.alreadyContains),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.Emptyinput), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else {
                    arrylist.add(getInput);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arrylist);
                    lst.setAdapter(adapter);
                    lst.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(" ");

                }
            }
        }
    });


        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(MainActivity.this.arrylist.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.delete_isEmpty), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    lst.setAdapter(null);
                    // I need to use notifityDataSetChanged, but cannot access my adapter 


                }
            }
        });


}
```

}

Comment: You can alaways get the adapter from ListView, like: ArrayAdapter<String> tmpAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) lst.getAdapter();. Hope this help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be this can help.
Declare your adapter globally(where you have declared Button,EditText...) and initialize it where you have actually initialized it (in btn click listener)

And for accessing it again in btn_delete try this

```
if(adapter!=null)
{
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Let me know if it helps